# About a property of continuous functions

Tags: analysis

> Let $g : [1, 25] \to \mathbb{R}$ be a continuous function. Show that there are real constants, $m$ and $M$ such that $mx \leq g(x) \leq Mx$, for all $x \in [1, 25]$.

Can anyone direct me on how to show that this statement is true ?

Comment: What can you deduce from $g$ being continuous on a closed interval?

Comment: Note that $g(x)/x$ is a continuous in $[1,25]$.

Answer (score 1):

Using the fact that a continuous function attains both its maximum and minimum on a closed bounded interval, we may apply this to $$f(x) : = \frac{g(x)}{x}$$ yields the desired result.

Note that $m : = \min_{ x \in [1,25]} \left| \frac{g(x)}{x} \right|$ and $M : =\max_{x \in [1,25]} \left| \frac{g(x)}{x} \right|$.

Please let me know if you have any more questions.